# Firebase database get value and set help Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a ticket app. The number of ticket is limited (1 to 100).

Set Value:
When some one buy a ticket his Uid will be set with the ticket number. But the process I am using is too complicated. Is there any simple system for this.

[image: Firebase Database]

...

```
private void buyTicket() {
    
    ticketRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ticket");


    HashMap<String, Object> ticketMap = new HashMap<>();
    ticketMap.put("59", fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    ticketRef.updateChildren(ticketMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
        {

            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {

                Toast.makeText(AddDetailsActivity.this, "Ticket Successfully bought", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
    
}
```

...

Get Value:
In  "MyTickeActivity" I want to show all the ticket the user bought. But If I use the system I know the coding will be lengthy. Can you suggest any simple process.

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you further with that. What did you do based on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The process sounds fairly straightforward (if possibly a bit verbose in code):

1. Read all tickets that were bought
2. Find a random ticket slot that hasn't been bought yet
3. Try to write your own UID to this ticket slot

If step 3 fails (due to the security rules that allow one to only claim tickets that have no owner yet), retry either from step 2 or step 3.